# GraphQL error: Expected type Int. Int cannot represent non-integer value

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm currently learning `GraphQL` with `Apollo` for React and I have a question that I can't find the answer online: 
I've done a form to send data for my mongoDB and I have this query:

```
const addContactMutation = gql`
    mutation($name: String!, $address: String!, $vat: Int!, $zip: String!, $email: String!, $contact: Int!){
        addContact(name: $name, address: $address, vat: $vat, zip: $zip, email: $email, contact: $contact){
            name
            vat
            email
        }
    }
`
```

However, my `$vat` and `$contact` are big numbers and when submit the form I receive this error:

> Variable "$vat" got invalid value "232214336"; Expected type Int. Int cannot represent non-integer value

Which type should I use for that?

Answer (score 4):

`232214336` is not so big, the max int number is `9007199254740991`

```js
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
```

I think the problem is you've passed a string value `"232214336"` when an Int value is expected as the error says `Expected type Int`, so you need to convert the value to an integer before or when passing variables to the mutation using `parseInt()`

```
addContact({ variables: { vat: parseInt(vat, 10), contact: parseInt(contact, 10), ... } })
```

Comment: what if the bigint is that big, you can't just parseInt so what do you do for graphQL for true bigint values?

Comment: @PositiveGuy you can use a custom scalar type or a bigint-graphql js library

Answer (score 3):

This error also happens when a database field that is typed as an integer, contains a value of NULL, and that field is returned by your GraphQL query.  One way to fix this, is to set up your database to give integer fields a default value so that they are never NULL when the row is created.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem before and I resolved it by :
first I checked if the order of types in the front-end is the same as in graphql-types
then
in the **input** form I replaced: **target.value**
by: **target.valueAsNumber**

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered a similar and weird kind of issue, as types were mentioned clearly but that wasn't accepted in variables by [graphql-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-request) version `3.1.4`, I mapped them again in a variable that is working at my end so far.

```
const variables = {
    orderId: +orderId,
    vendorIds: vendorIds.map(id => +id),
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in my Grapql+NestJs application. What I did is changed the graph field type from Int to Float. It works